# "Could not read status line" error when trying to commit locked file

Tags: svn

I'm using svn locking for the first time. I can lock and unlock files, but I get an error if I try to commit a file that's locked:

```
$ svn lock report.docx 
'report.docx' locked by user 'lorin'.

Edit, edit, edit...

$ svn st
M    K  report.docx
$ svn commit -m "Edited the introduction"
Sending        myproject/report.docx
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: CHECKOUT of '/reports/!svn/ver/6049/myproject/report.docx': Could not read status line: Secure connection truncated (https://www.example.com)
```

If I unlock the file, then I can commit.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using [Locking](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.locking.html) correctly (at least according to the docs). I would question why you are doing that with SVN, but that's not your question. ;)

[Have you checked out this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613149/svn-could-not-read-status-line-connection-was-closed-by-server) that had a similar error?

Comment: I'm coordinating with other people on editing a binary file. In this case, it's a Word document.

Answer (score 0):

Please be informed that the Subversion lock and unlock commands do not work properly in an environment where replication is being used. Subversion does not currently provide a means for replicating locks between repositories, or even via repository dump files. Consequently, locks are all stored in the master repository and they do not exist on the replicated repositories.

Visit the following link to read more about this

https://ctf.open.collab.net/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.svnedge/wiki/Replication#section-Replication-NoSupportForSvnLockUnlock

Comment: FYI: VisualSVN Server's Multisite Repository Replication features supports locking and replicating locks: https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/multisite-replication/