# SVN Could not read status line error on checkout

Tags: svn, connection

I used to be able to check out/in from our SVN repository at work. Then I did a clean install of OS X 10.8 due to some issues. Everything else is great but now I can't check out or update. No one else here is experiencing problems.

Here's the error I'm getting:

> svn: OPTIONS of 'http://subversion.myhost.com/svn/repository/trunk': Could not read status line: connection was closed by server (http://subversion.myhost.com)

I've done a lot of googling over the last couple of days but nothing I found was helpful. The most informative page is here: [SVN: Could not read status line: connection was closed by server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613149/svn-could-not-read-status-line-connection-was-closed-by-server)

Stuff I've tried:

- changing http -> https -> svn (connections to https/svn are refused)
- checking for proxy/firewall blocking (couldn't find any--but perhaps there's something I missed?)
- loading the repository from the web interface (can browse it just fine, but still can't check out)
- updating subversion (was using svn from Xcode 4.5) then installed svn (1.6.18) via macports (still getting same error)
- wiped my subversion preferences in ~/.subversion
- double/triple/quad+ checked the URL (same every time)
- checking out stuff from a completely different repository off-site (got the same error)
- drinking lots of Mountain Dew and hoping for inspiration (getting jittery but nothing else has changed)

Anyone have other ideas?

Comment: I did some more digging, and apparently something was blocking all http traffic from the svn client. After another day of searching I found out that it was the Cisco VPN client I had installed, which had a process that filtered it out even when I wasn't connected to the VPN.

Comment: Thanks for that! Other users might benefit from knowing that in my case a service `Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Agent` `vpnagent.exe` also needed to be stopped.

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this question and your respective solution.  I hit the same problem and never would have guessed it was the damn Cisco VPN client.  As Craig mentioned, there is a background process that also needs to be quelled, but everything worked once that was stopped. Cheers!

Comment: I've found a solution for mac here. http://superuser.com/a/579485/290504

Answer (score 2):

I just got burned by this too; thanks for pointing me in the direction of the culprit (the damned VPN client). I note that it does this fuckery even with the VPN connection **disabled**, lest you think that you can stop it from screwing with your network stack by asking nicely!

Where did you discover it was the client? I am going to have to fight this one out with my IT team so was curious what other information was out there.

Answer (score 1):

What if the repository is behind a firewall and you need the VPN client to connect?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workable solution for using the SVN client with Cisco Any Connect client 3.1.x for Apple Mac OS X 10.9.x.

In summary, uninstall the Cisco Any Connect web security module.

Issue and solution summary posted at

Super User - SVN Error when connecting from MacBook

https://superuser.com/a/704711

and at

Super User - SVN Connection Not Successful

https://superuser.com/a/579485

- Tim

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced same issue but we are using Juniper VPN. Shutting down all VPN processes helped to resolve it.