# error with SVN - PROPFIND

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm having an issue and I've tried lots of things and I'm not sure what to do next, so I was hoping someone out there might help..

I have a repo hosted on a server and I use TortoiseSVN to perform my SVN operations (checkout, update, commit, etc..).  Up until yesterday it was working just fine, but today something happened.. whenever I try to update or make a commit or do anything, I get the following error (edited to remove server specifics)

> PROPFIND of '/path/to/repo': Could not read status line: connection
>   was closed by  server (http://myrepo.server.com)

**I have tried the following:**

- Updating to the latest version of TortoiseSVN
- Deleting and re-checking out the repo
- Uninstalling and re-installing TortoiseSVN
- Clearing my stored credentials and re-entering them in
- Verifying my credentials - my coworker is able to use my
  credentials to checkout the repo just fine
- Using my coworker's credentials – I get the same error when
  attempting to do anything
- Trying different repos not hosted on this server (works)
- Verifying with my coworker if he is having issues with the repo – he is NOT
  having issues with checking out or updating the repo with his own or
  my credentials
- Trying on different computers in my house.  I've tried on 3 different computers and I'm having the same problem
- running `svnadmin verify` and `svnadmin recover` on the repo.  Everything comes back shiny, but problem persists.

**I AM able to:**

- Go to the repo URL in my BROWSER and use my credentials and browse the repo
- SSH into the server that hosts the repo

I have also tried to research using keywords of this error and have been unable to come up with anything.. anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Is this a repo over http(s)? If so, what do the logs of that webserver say?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613149/svn-could-not-read-status-line-connection-was-closed-by-server

Comment: it is not a protocol issue.  The repo is http